# Is there any way to get a bean with prototype scope but not making a new bean every time you get it?

Tags: java, spring

I do not want a new instant for the bean every time I call it. I need a constant value, even though it has to be a prototype bean.

Comment: Not understand what you want. What you mean by constant value? Can you post your source code?

Comment: The very definition of a prototype bean is one where the context makes a new bean every time you get it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store your prototype bean in a singleton bean's property. On this way, you don't have to create an instance every time you have to access the bean.

However, if you REALLY nead a "constant" value, use a singleton. By constant on this case, I mean that there's only going to be one instance.